# Creating a class that inherits from another class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, juce

I am trying to learn C++ from Juce and building an audio synthesizer.

I have a synthesizer that can output audio from an oscillator class (`MaxiOsc`) in short like this:

```
class SynthVoice : public SynthesiserVoice
{

private:

    MaxiOsc testOsc;
    double frequency = 0; // frequency is then changed by another function by new notes from the keyboard of course ...

public:

    double oscOutput()
    {
        return testOsc.sinewave(frequency);
    }

void renderNextBlock (AudioBuffer <float> &outputBuffer, int startSample, int numSamples) override
    {
        for (int sample = 0; sample < numSamples; ++sample)
        {

            for (int channel = 0; channel < outputBuffer.getNumChannels(); ++channel)
            {
                outputBuffer.addSample(channel, startSample, oscOutput() //MAIN OUTPUT HERE
            }
            ++startSample;
        }

    }
```

I am trying to create a new class called `ModalUnit` which inherits from `MaxiOsc` and creates a `MaxiOsc` object within it. The idea is to use `ModalUnit` in place of `MaxiOsc` in the synthesizer code above and add extra processing to the `ModalUnit` class code eventually.

Here's what I have for the `ModalUnit` class:

```
class ModalUnit    : public MaxiOsc
{
public:
    ModalUnit()
    {

    }

    double getOutput(double frequency)
    {
        output = testOsc.sinewave(frequency);
        return output;
    }


private:
    MaxiOsc testOsc;
    double output = 0.0;

};
```

But when I try to implement this in the synthesizer code it won't output any audio:

```
class SynthVoice : public SynthesiserVoice
{

private:

    ModalUnit testModalUnit;
    double frequency = 0; // frequency is then changed by another function by new notes from the keyboard of course ...

public:

    double modalUnitOutput()
    {
        return testModalUnit.getOutput(frequency);
    }

void renderNextBlock (AudioBuffer <float> &outputBuffer, int startSample, int numSamples) override
    {
        for (int sample = 0; sample < numSamples; ++sample)
        {

            for (int channel = 0; channel < outputBuffer.getNumChannels(); ++channel)
            {
                outputBuffer.addSample(channel, startSample, modalUnitOutput() //MAIN OUTPUT HERE
            }
            ++startSample;
        }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong in this new class creation? I basically just want the `ModalUnit` class to create the `MaxiOsc` within it and then output from this to start.

How do I do that or fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you both inherit and have an object of the parent class as member?

Comment: Not necessarily any good reason. I don't know how to make this work. I've tried multiple ways and nothing comes out. Eg. I also tried using in the synth code `double modalUnitOutput() { return testModalUnit.sinewave(frequency);    }` to use the MaxiOsc function directly and it still won't output audio. Can you suggest what I ought to be doing to make this work? I've read many tutorials on inheritance but I don't seem to be getting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is happening is that you are both inheriting and having a member of `class MaxiOSc`. When inheriting a class, all members of parent are now members of the child class. By including an object of the parent class, these members are duplicated.

In your `double getOutput(double frequency)` function in `ModalUnit` you output using the member object of type `MaxiOsc`. Meanwhile, when calling methods inherited from `MaxiOsc` to the `ModalUnit` the inherited members are used.

Answer (score 0):

The only diffrence is the param of function getOutput.It's passed by value

```
double getOutput(double frequency)
{
    output = testOsc.sinewave(frequency);
    return output;
}
```

So the member *frequency* will change when call getOutput function.The member *frequency* is used in other place? you can check the value when you're debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try removing the injected MaxiOsc from ModelUnit and just go with inheritance. In ModelUnit, override the functions from MaxiOsc you want to do extra processing in, then  call the base class's implementation from inside your version of the function.